# PowerShell input to function not work when pipeling input

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function that I inherited.  it works fine when using no input or providing a single server name as input.

Function works when running like this

`Get-DiskUtil` or

```
Get-DiskUtil computername
```

But if I try

`Get-Content c:\psfiles\servers.txt | Foreach-Object {Get-DiskUtil}`  (this give the output of the local machine three times if I have three server listed in servers.txt).

or

```
Get-Content C:\psfiles\servers.txt | Get-DiskUtil
```

The result only gives the output of the local machine name and this error three times.

Can someone tell me why Get-Content does not work and how I might go about fixing this?

```
computername=$_ : The term 'computername=$_' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Data\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyFunctions\Get-DiskUtil.ps1:4 char:10
+ if ($_) {computername=$_}
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (computername=$_:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Get-DiskUtil:

```
Function Get-DiskUtil {
Param([string] $computername=$env:computername)
Process {
if ($_) {computername=$_}
gwmi win32_logicaldisk -fi "drivetype=3" -comp $computername |
Select @{Name="Computername";Expression={$_.systemName}},
DevicedID,
@{Name="SizeGB";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}},
@{Name="FreeGB";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Freespace/1GB)}},
@{Name="UsedGB";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f (($_.Size-$_.FreeSpace)/1GB)}},
@{Name="PerFreeGB";Expression={"{0:P2}" -f ($_.Freespace/$_.size)}}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo to me.
This line:

```
if ($_) {computername=$_}
```

should be:

```
if ($_) {$computername=$_}
```

There are many advantages to using advanced functions, but it's not required to have a function that accepts input from the pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you have created a function.  Functions do not accept input from the pipeline you need to create an advanced function.

```
Function Get-DiskUtil {
     [CmdLetBinding]
     Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
          [string] $computername=$env:computername)
     )
```

This will allow that paramater to be taken in on the pipe line.  Not you could also solve this by rearaging your calling code

```
Get-Content c:\psfiles\servers.txt | % {Get-DiskUtil $_}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]` attribute to your parameter declaration. You also need to declare the `$ComputerName` parameter as an array, since it will accept either a single value, or an array of values.

Here is the modified function.

```
function Get-DiskUtil {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]] $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    process {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" -ComputerName $ComputerName |
        Select-Object -Property @{Name="Computername"; Expression={$_.systemName} },
        DevicedID,
        @{ Name="SizeGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}},
        @{ Name="FreeGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Freespace/1GB)}},
        @{ Name="UsedGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}" -f (($_.Size-$_.FreeSpace)/1GB)}},
        @{ Name="PerFreeGB"; Expression={"{0:P2}" -f ($_.Freespace/$_.size)}}
    }
}

# Call the function, passing in an array of values
'localhost','localhost' | Get-DiskUtil
```

Comment: This works as posted.  Not declaring the $ComputerName is why I was getting the output error.  Thank you very much and Happy New Year.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you're up and running! Cheers